# Prolog - How to use multiple pl file inside pl file

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm new at Prolog. I have two files. One of them is "names.pl" and the other one is "verbs.pl". This both files have facts. "names.pl" has fact about a lot of noun etc. The fact's name is relation.

the template of those files: relation(notion_1,relation,notion_2)
Example:

```
relation('accumulator','shape','rectangle').
relation('packing','shape','rectangle').
relation('gold','live / lifeless','lifeless').
```

My question is, how can I use those 2 pl file in one file? How can I import those files in one file? How can I use this "relation" fact in 3rd file using/importing "verbs.pl" and "names.pl" ?

Comment: Do you want an introduction into the module system or do you just need the [`consult`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=consult/1) predicate?

Comment: consult doens't worked. I tried.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? what have you tried? It should work. Are you getting any specific error or warning messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `consult`, as you're using swi, you can use the short form. SWI automatically appends `.pl` to the filename.

```
% short form:
:- [verbs, names].

%longer form:
:- consult(varbs).
:- consult('names.pl').
```

If you have `relation` facts in both of the files, you can use `include`:

```
:-include('verbs.pl').
:-include('names.pl').
```

These two assume that you set up a third file.

You also can declare a predicate as `multifile`, with

```
:-multifile(relation/3).
```

Then prolog won't overwrite the declarations of previously definded predicates.

Here is the [documentation of SWI for loading and consulting](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=consulting).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to have a third file with the contents:

```
:- include(file1).
:- include(file2).
```

Check the documentation of your Prolog system on the `include/1` standard directive.

Comment: He is using swi, the documentation is here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/1